# What is the grammar of "my heart burdened be"?

Tags: inversion, poetry, rhetoric

I have some trouble understanding a line from the song, "You Raise Me Up"

> When I am down and, oh my soul, so weary
>   When troubles come and **my heart burdened be**
>   Then, I am still and wait here in the silence
>   Until you come and sit awhile with me

I can guess the meaning of the line, "my heart burdened be."
But I can't get it grammatically. I think it should be "my heart is burdened." 
I understand it's because it is a song but I'm a Korean English teacher. 
I want to make my students understand the line clearly.
Help me, please!

Comment: @Mari-Lou The title of the song is given in the title of the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's a ripoff of Danny Boy called "You Raise Me Up"

Comment: Songs are generally not a good way to learn English grammar.  Song writers and singers often use nonstandard grammar either to fit the music better or to rhyme better.

Comment: I originally heard this line as 'My heart burdens me', which is undoubtedly correct grammar.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the meaning. You are also correct that this construction is not standard modern English, at least not in the US.

The author is Irish, and his construction may reflect usage in some Irish dialect of English or a translation from some feature of Erse. Or, more likely, he may have just played a bit loose with English grammar to force a rhyme.

Comment: It's not Irish, it's simply a poetic inversion of word order.

Comment: @Robusto **when my heart burdened be** is not standard English in the US, and it is not just an inversion of word order. That use  of **be** Is not standard, at least not in the US, and is inconsistent with the other verbs in the quoted lines. To let a teacher infer that **when my heart burdened be** is a model for contemporary American English is not something I want to do. An earlier comment pointed out that trying to learn English from the lyrics of popular songs is probably a poor idea.

Comment: It's also subjunctive, which is still standard English, and it *is* an inversion.

Comment: Did I say it was not an inversion? And if it be a subjunctive, then why are the other verbs not subjunctive. The writer was simply too lazy to find a rhyme in modern colloquial English.